# How to create dynamic menu in antdesign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to create dynamic menu in antdesign, in 4.19.5 version

Here code for static menu

```
<Menu selectable selectedKeys={activeKey}>
      
      { <Menu.SubMenu title="Main Title 1" >
        <Menu.Item key={'13'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 1</Link> </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key={'14'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 2</Link></Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key={'15'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 3</Link></Menu.Item>
      </Menu.SubMenu>}

      { <Menu.SubMenu title="Main Title 2">
        <Menu.Item key={'16'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 4 </Link></Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key={'17'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 5 </Link></Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key={'18'} onClick={(item) => SetActivekey([item.key])}><Link to={{  }} > Sub Title 6</Link></Menu.Item>
      </Menu.SubMenu>}

   </Menu>
```

Below is the data which I want to use to create menu

```
 var Arr=[{ 'Main Title 1': ['Sub Title 1', 'Sub Title 2', 'Sub Title 3'] }, { 'Main Title 2': ['Sub Title 4', 'Sub Title 5', 'Sub Title 6'] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a function to construct that Submenus, for example

```
const arr = [
  { "Main Title 1": ["Sub Title 1", "Sub Title 2", "Sub Title 3"] },
  { "Main Title 2": ["Sub Title 4", "Sub Title 5", "Sub Title 6"] }
];

function constructSubmenus(arr) {
    return arr.map((e) => (
      <Menu.SubMenu title={Object.keys(e)[0]}>
        {Object.values(e)[0].map((f, i) => (
          <Menu.Item key={i}> {f} </Menu.Item>
        ))}
      </Menu.SubMenu>
    ));
  }
  return <Menu selectable>{constructSubmenus(arr)}</Menu>;
```

Another option is you can utilize the `Menu`'s attribute `items` if you can construct the array that can satisfy as the arguments for that attribute. You can check it on the documentation https://ant.design/components/menu